# How to temporarily uppercase the string variable in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, string, foreach, uppercase

I currently have the following code:

```
foreach (string s in lstSearchStrings.Items)
{
    int cnt = CountSubStrings(fileText, s);
    if (cnt > 0)
    {
        string cs = cnt.ToString().PadLeft(5);
        lstCounts.Items.Add(cs);
        counter++;
    }
    else break;
}
```

I need to temporarily uppercase s in order to look for it in an already uppercased fileText string, but I can't because it gives an error when I try this:

```
foreach (string s in lstSearchStrings.Items)
{
    if (chkExactCase.Checked == false)
    {
        string us = s.ToUpper();
        s = us;
    }
    int cnt = CountSubStrings(fileText, s);
    if (cnt > 0)
    {
        string cs = cnt.ToString().PadLeft(5);
        lstCounts.Items.Add(cs);
        counter++;
    }
    else break;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `I can't because it gives an error when I try this:` **Always** say **what the error is**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change loop variable s, use variable us instead:

```
foreach (string s in lstSearchStrings.Items)
{
    var us = chkExactCase.Checked ? s : s.ToUpper();
    int cnt = CountSubStrings(fileText, us);
    if (cnt > 0)
    {
        string cs = cnt.ToString().PadLeft(5);
        lstCounts.Items.Add(cs);
        counter++;
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: Ya, I should have added that I needed to do an if/else for testing whether it needs to be uppercased or not. But you verified my solution so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
foreach (string s in lstSearchStrings.Items)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    if (chkExactCase.Checked == false)
    {
        cnt = CountSubStrings(fileText, s.ToUpper());
    }
    else
    {
        cnt = CountSubStrings(fileText, s);
    }
    if (cnt > 0)
    {
        string cs = cnt.ToString().PadLeft(5);
        lstCounts.Items.Add(cs);
        counter++;
    }
    else break;
}
```